# Unbound variable not causing exit from subshell when set -eu

Tags: bash, shell

```
$ cat test.sh
set -eu
echo "`wc -l < $DNE`"
echo should not get here

$ /bin/bash test.sh
test.sh: line 2: DNE: unbound variable

should not get here
```

I'm running bash version 4.1.2. Is there a way to make sure all such usage of unbound variables in subshells cause the script to exit without having to modify each call involving a subshell?

Comment: @Phil's answer worked on Linux, OS X, and Solaris. You might consider accepting it.

Comment: It's a decent alternative but doesn't address the original question's requirement of "without having to modify each call". If the flags did as desired, it's more set-and-forget than having to remember to do something each time a variable is used in a certain situation.

Answer (score 12):

The better solution to ensure variable sanitisation

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

if [[ ${1-} ]]; then
  DNE=$1
else
  echo "ERROR: Please enter a valid filename" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi
```

By putting a hyphen in to the variable name inside curly braces like this allows bash to sanely handle the variable being undefined.  I also highly recommend looking at the Google shell style guide, it's a great reference https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml

```
[[ -z ${variable-} ]] \
  && echo "ERROR: Unset variable \${variable}" \
  && exit 1 \
  || echo "INFO: Using variable (${variable})"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a temporary variable so as to let test.sh process know about the failure of `wc`. You can change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
out=$(wc -l < $DNE)
echo $out
echo should not get here
```

Now, you won't see the `should not get here` if wc fails.

Comment: Thanks but if I could always remember to do things correctly, I wouldn't need the -eu options at all to catch the mistakes that bash would otherwise let through :) I am looking for a way to tell bash to be less permissive about errors without changing all the code -eu applies to.

Comment: You check the return codes of each command and print appropriate msgs/error handling. -e is an option when exiting at any failure is desirable. Bash is an interpreted language, so the such joys are only in compiled languages :) But it provides reasonable options such -e here.

Comment: do you believe there is some way to do this without using `-e` ?

Comment: @AquariusPower `-e` is really for debugging purposes. It doesn't provide any useful info; it just fails. Other than that, it's usual way of checking for errors is to catch the return code using the variable `$?`.

Comment: I just want the code to auto-exit if the error is "unbound variable", because all other errors I take care manually; may be a new question would be cool? :)

Comment: @AquariusPower If you are only concerned about variables not set being used then you could do: `set -o nounset`.

Comment: I saw it is about subshell/child, check the question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146224/bash-nounset-on-sub-shell-child-doesnt-force-main-script-to-exit-how-to-work)